# Setting .authorize_egress() with protocol set to all

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to execute the following code

```
def createSecurityGroup(self, securitygroupname): 
    conn = boto3.resource('ec2') 
    response = conn.create_security_group(GroupName=securitygroupname, Description = 'test')

VPC_NAT_SecurityObject = createSecurityGroup("mysecurity_group")

response_egress_all =  VPC_NAT_SecurityObject.authorize_egress(
        IpPermissions=[{'IpProtocol': '-1'}])
```

and getting the below exception

> EXCEPTION : 
>   *An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress operation: Only Amazon VPC security
>   groups may be used with this operation.*

I tried several different combinations but not able to set the protocol to all . I used '-1' as explained in the boto3 documentation.  Can somebody pls suggest how to get this done.

Comment: Where did you get `VPC_NAT_SecurityObject` from? Part of boto3 API? 
Are you using VPC ?

Comment: Its a return type from the following function  . Yes, I am using VPC and its a part of boto3                                                        def createSecurityGroup(self, securitygroupname):
        conn = boto3.resource('ec2')
        response =conn.create_security_group(GroupName=securitygroupname, Description = 'test')

Comment: Well, when you using `boto3.resource`, you must specify the VPC  name. connecting to boto3.resource.ec2 is not enough

Answer (score 0):

(UPDATE)

1.boto3.resource("ec2") class actually a high level class wrap around the client class. You must create an extract class instantiation using boto3.resource("ec2").Vpc in order to attach to specific VPC ID e.g.

```
import boto3
ec2_resource = boto3.resource("ec2") 
myvpc = ec2_resource.Vpc("vpc-xxxxxxxx") 
response = myvpc.create_security_group(
   GroupName = securitygroupname, 
   Description = 'test')
```

2.Sometime it is straightforward to use boto3.client("ec2") If you check boto3 EC2 client [create_security_group](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.create_security_group), you will see this:

```
response = client.create_security_group(
  DryRun=True|False,
  GroupName='string',
  Description='string',
  VpcId='string'
 )
```

If you use automation script/template to rebuild the VPC, e.g. salt-cloud, you need give the VPC a tag name in order to acquire it automatically from boto3 script. This will save all the hassle when AWS migrate all the AWS resources ID from 8 alphanumeric to 12 or 15 character.

Another option is using cloudformation that let you put everything and specify variable in a template to recreate the VPC stack.

Comment: Thanks  @mootmoot .    I was able to achieve what I am trying to to do by  making a client call and then wrapping that up with a resource object . It is something like this
        responseGroupid = conn_client.create_security_group(GroupName=securitygroupname, Description = 'test', VpcId=vpc.id)
        security_group = conn_resource.SecurityGroup(responseGroupid['GroupId']) . Sowhere resource object doesn't support certain functionality. Make a call with client and wrap it up resource.

Comment: @pradeep : In fact, boto3 resources class are wrapper for boto3.client.  i will update my answer on that part.